# Calculate the minimum value of $\left|\frac{a^2 - bc}{b - c}\right| + \left|\frac{b^2 - ca}{c - a}\right| + \left|\frac{c^2 - ab}{a - b}\right|$.

Tags: inequality, optimization, summation, maxima-minima, absolute-value

> Given positives $a, b, c$ such that $abc = 1$, if possible, calculate the minimum value of $$\left|\frac{a^2 - bc}{b - c}\right| + \left|\frac{b^2 - ca}{c - a}\right| + \left|\frac{c^2 - ab}{a - b}\right|$$

Without loss of generalisation, assume that $a \le b \le c$.

We have that $$\left|\frac{a^2 - bc}{b - c}\right| + \left|\frac{b^2 - ca}{c - a}\right| + \left|\frac{c^2 - ab}{a - b}\right| \ge \frac{c^2 - ba}{b - a} + \frac{a^2 - bc}{b - c}$$

$$ = \frac{(c + a)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - bc - ca - ab)}{(c - b)(b - a)} \ (1)$$

Let $c' = b - a, a' = c - b \iff c = a' + b, a = b - c'$, $(1)$ becomes $$\frac{(2b - c' + a')(c'^2 + c'a' + a'^2)}{c'a'}$$

and $(b - c')b(b + a') = b^3 - (c' - a')b^2 - c'a'b = 1$

$$\iff (2b - c' + a')b^2 = b^3 + c'a'b + 1 \iff 2b - c' + a' = \frac{b^3 + c'a'b + 1}{b^2}$$

Another idea I had was that $\left|\dfrac{a^2 - bc}{b - c}\right| + \left|\dfrac{b^2 - ca}{c - a}\right| + \left|\dfrac{c^2 - ab}{a - b}\right|$

$$ = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\text{cyc}}\left(|c - a|\left|\frac{2(b^2 - ca)}{(c - a)^2}\right|\right) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\text{cyc}}\left(|c - a|\left|\frac{2b^2 - c^2 - a^2}{(c - a)^2} + 1\right|\right)$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2}\left[(c - b)\left(\left|\frac{2(b^2 - a^2)}{(b - c)^2} + \frac{c^2 - b^2}{(b - c)^2} - 1\right| + \left|\frac{b^2 - a^2}{(c - a)^2} - \frac{c^2 - b^2}{(c - a)^2} + 1\right|\right)\right.$$

$$\left. + (b - a)\left(\left|\frac{b^2 - a^2}{(c - a)^2} - \frac{c^2 - b^2}{(c - a)^2} + 1\right| + \left|\frac{b^2 - a^2}{(a - b)^2} + \frac{2(c^2 - b^2)}{(a - b)^2} + 1\right|\right)\right]$$

$$ \ge \frac{1}{2}\left[(c - b)\left(\frac{2(b^2 - a^2)}{(b - c)^2} + \frac{c^2 - b^2}{(b - c)^2} + \frac{b^2 - a^2}{(c - a)^2} - \frac{c^2 - b^2}{(c - a)^2}\right)\right.$$

$$\left. + (b - a)\left(\frac{b^2 - a^2}{(c - a)^2} - \frac{c^2 - b^2}{(c - a)^2} + \frac{b^2 - a^2}{(a - b)^2} + \frac{2(c^2 - b^2)}{(a - b)^2} + 2\right)\right]$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2}\left[(c^2 - b^2)\left(\frac{1}{c - b} - \frac{1}{c - a} + \frac{2}{b - a}\right) + (b^2 - a^2)\left(\frac{2}{c - b} + \frac{1}{c - a} + \frac{1}{b - a}\right)\right] + (b - a)$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b^2 + c^2 - 2a^2}{c - b} + \frac{2b^2 - c^2 - a^2}{c - a} + \frac{2c^2 - a^2 - b^2}{b - a}\right) + (b - a)$$

There must have been something wrong, but that's all I have for now.

Comment: I think there's no need of $\geq$, a simple $>$ will do as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\left|\frac{a^2-bc}{b-c}\right|=\sqrt{\left(\left|\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2-bc}{b-c}\right|\right)^2}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2-bc}{b-c}\right)^2-2\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a^2-bc)(b^2-ac)}{(b-c)(c-a)}+2\sum_{cyc}\left|\frac{(a^2-bc)(b^2-ac)}{(b-c)(c-a)}\right|}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{-2\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a^2-bc)(b^2-ac)}{(b-c)(c-a)}-2\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a^2-bc)(b^2-ac)}{(b-c)(c-a)}}=$$
$$=\sqrt{4(a+b+c)^2}=2(a+b+c)\geq6.$$
Now, prove that we got an infimum and the minimum does not exist.

Comment: 2(a+b+c) > 6 , this implies a+b+c>3 but how?

Comment: @Anindya Prithvi  By AM-GM: $a+b+c\geq3\sqrt[3]{abc}=3.$

Comment: aaah...right, i skipped thinking about abc for the moment

Comment: How did you get the intuition to write the first argument in your proof? It just seems non trivial to me

Comment: @Anindya Prithvi  I used $x^2\geq0$ and $|x|\geq-x$. I hope now it's clear.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  It is a nice solution (+1). There is typo after 1st '='.

Comment: Your solution can be rewritten as: Let $x = \frac{a^2-bc}{b-c}, y = \frac{b^2-ca}{c-a}, z = \frac{c^2-ab}{a-b}$. Note that $xy+yz+zx = -(a+b+c)^2$. We have $(|x| + |y| + |z|)^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2 + 2|xy| + 2|yz| + 2|zx| \ge (x+y+z)^2 - 2xy - 2yz - 2zx  - 2xy - 2yz - 2zx \ge -4(xy+yz+zx) = 4(a+b+c)^2$ (Remark: $xy+yz+zx = -(a+b+c)^2$ is a nice identity.)

Comment: Thank you @River Li for your interest.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
\frac{bc-a^2}{c-b}+\frac{|b^2-ca|}{c-a}+\frac{c^2-ab}{b-a}\geq \frac{bc-a^2}{c-b}-\frac{|b^2-ca|}{c-a}+\frac{c^2-ab}{b-a}
$$
with equality only if $b=1$ and $c=\frac{1}{a}$. Now insert $b$ and $c$ to obtain
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{a}-a^2}{\frac{1}{a}-1}+\frac{\frac{1}{a^2}-a}{1-a}=\frac{1-a^3}{1-a}+\frac{1-a^3}{a^2-a^3}
$$
Differentiation suggest a minimum at $a=1$ but we are not allowed to set $a=1$ however we can take the limit $a\to 1^-$. Do it and use L' Hosptial.
$$
\lim_{a\to 1^-}\frac{-3a^2}{-1}+\frac{-3a^2}{2a-3a^2}=6.
$$
So, minimum value 6 is obtained when we set $b=1$ and take limits $a\to 1^-$ and $c\to 1^+$ with $c=\frac{1}{a}$.

**EDIT: Adding more stuff for clarity**

There can only be equality in the inequality if $|b^2-ca|=-|b^2-ca|$ which means equality is when $b^2=ca$, i.e. both sides are zero. Multiply by $b$ and we have $b^3=cab=1$ which gives $b=1$.

Since $b=1$ we get $ac=1$. Choose $a=0.5$ and $c=2$ then we have $\frac{2-0.25}{2-0.5}+\frac{4-0.5}{1-0.5}=\frac{49}{6}>\frac{36}{6}=6$.

Clearly $a<1<c$ otherwise we get division by zero.

Next define $P(a)=\frac{1-a^3}{1-a}+\frac{1-a^3}{a^2-a^3}=a^2+a+2+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a^2}$ which has extremum at $a=1$. Since we cannot choose $a=1$ we instead take the limit $\lim_{a\to 1^-}P(a)=6$ which is OK since the function $P(a)$ is continuous for $0<a<1$. And we have shown that $P(0.5)>6$ so therefore, because of continuity, we do not need to take second derivative of $P(a)$.

What if $|b^2-ca|<-|b^2-ca|$? Well, it cannot be true since a positive number is larger than a negative number. We have now proven global infimum is 6.

Comment: What happens for $b\neq1$?

Comment: My question is what is your solution for $b\neq1$?

Comment: Even for $b=1$ you did not prove that $6$ is an infimum.

Comment: There we go. :) Thanks for comments. I made things more clear now.

Comment: yeah this proves that on the smaller set $\Omega = \{(a,1,\frac 1a)| a> 0\}$, $f(a,b,c) > 6.$ Conceivably, it could happen that $f(a,b,c) \leq 6$ outside of $\Omega. $

Comment: There are 6 ways to get $f(a,b,c)=6$ by taking limits. Without loss of generality I proved one way.

Comment: @Mikael Helin  Why for the starting problem  the minimum occurs for $b^2=ac$? After your fixing I see that  you solved this problem for $b^2=ac$ and I did not see a proof for $b^2\neq ac$. See also the  dezdichado's comment.

Comment: @Mikael Helin I wait your reaction...

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg $b^2=ac$ is taken in consideration of the primary question |a| can never be negative the least it can be is zero, Helin could have also taken $c^2-ab=0$ would've worked the same

Comment: @Anindya Prithvi But what happens if $b^2-ac\neq0$, but the rest expression gets a less value? We need to prove an inequality for $b^2-ac\neq0.$ Without this proof the solution is absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question: $\lim_{h \to 0}6+h$

The given expression$$\left|\frac{a^2 - bc}{b - c}\right| + \left|\frac{b^2 - ca}{c - a}\right| + \left|\frac{c^2 - ab}{a - b}\right| $$
upon condition that $abc=1$

This can be rewritten as
$$\left|\frac{a^2 - \frac{1}{a}}{b - c}\right| + \left|\frac{b^2 - \frac{1}{b}}{c - a}\right| + \left|\frac{c^2 - \frac{1}{c}}{a - b}\right| $$ which is further reducable to $$\left|\frac{a-1}{b - c}(a+\frac{1}{a}+1)\right| + \left|\frac{b-1}{c-a}(b+\frac{1}{b}+1)\right| + \left|\frac{c-1}{a-b}(c+\frac{1}{c}+1)\right| $$

if $a,b,c >0$
this reduces to $$3\big(\left|\frac{a-1}{b - c}\right| + \left|\frac{b-1}{ c-a}\right| + \left|\frac{c-1}{a-b}\right|\big) $$

Note: *The reduction for $a+\frac{1}{a} +1>3$ and not $\geq 3$ because doing so would imply all variables equal $1$*

**The least value for this expression I could yield using $a$ fixed at 1 and manipulating $b,c$ was 6**

Since there's a modulus operation, the least we can get out of |x| is 0, so set $a=1$, by doing that we are left with
$$\left|\frac{b-1}{ c-1}\right| + \left|\frac{c-1}{b-1}\right|\ $$
which is definitely $$> 2$$ (remember $b$ and $c$ cannot be equal)

Hence the answer.

Comment: I considered we all know $-2 \geq x+1/x$ or $2 \leq x+1/x $ if x has a real domain.

Comment: You have demonstrated that the expression is always $\ge 6$, but why is that the *minimal* value? Can you show that the bound is sharp?

Comment: @MartinR did you mean this?

Comment: You claim that 6 is the *minimal* value. But perhaps the expression is always $\ge 7$? You have to show that $f(a, b, c)$ can be arbitrarily close to $6$, and I do not see that in your proof.

Comment: @MartinR No sweet sir, your claim is false https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f8xbneuuy8

Comment: I did not claim anything. *You* claim that the minimum is 6, but you do not prove it.

Comment: @MartinR I think youre asking me to prove that the minimum is always close to 6?

Comment: @MartinR if so, the claim of minimum being 6 sits right in the heart of the fact that x+1/x would be $\geq$ 2 which has been used twice while proving this.

Comment: After you set $a = 1$, $b$ and $c$ become reciprocals, so you can substitute and have only one unknown.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó good observation but the simplification of the proposed method would be the same as i have done , in the form of x+1/x